# Api-Platform: How to add filters for Hydra-Provider in admin view

Tags: react-admin, api-platform.com

My API has this in the response at the bottom:

```
"hydra:search": {
    "@type": "hydra:IriTemplate",
    "hydra:template": "/posts{?author,title}",
    "hydra:variableRepresentation": "BasicRepresentation",
    "hydra:mapping": [
      {
        "@type": "IriTemplateMapping",
        "variable": "author",
        "property": "author",
        "required": false
      },
      {
        "@type": "IriTemplateMapping",
        "variable": "title",
        "property": "title",
        "required": false
      }
    ]
  }
```

but i dont have any filters showing on the `posts`-list view. Do i have to actively enable/code this somewhere? The docs at https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html#adding-search-and-filters-to-the-list only refer to the "i have coded a component for the list-view" case. As im using api-platform, i read the REST-Api via `parseHydraDocumentation` (which i expected to do the "if response has `hydra:search` section in it, create the filter component"-work for me).